# Same SQL query which works in Teradata doesn't work in Fitnesse

Tags: teradata, fitnesse, teradata-sql-assistant

Same SQL query which works in Teradata SQL Assistant doesn't work in Fitnesse. I get below error when we run the query

*"SELECT failed. 3706: Syntax error: expected something between '(' and the 'SUBSTR' keyword*

I have faced the same problem in past. I understand the problem is with copy and paste. In past it was small query so I manually typed and it worked. But now my query expands over 300 lines, so I am not able to retype it. I even tried to copy and paste in plain text via notepad and notepad ++, but still unable to resolve it. Can you throw some light please?

Comment: Can you show the failing part of the query near SUBSTR?

Comment: Which fixture are you using to execute the query? Maybe you have the option to load the query from a file (which could be placed in the files section or bundled in Java). 300 lines of query does not sound very nice for the wiki...

Comment: Most often this is due to curved ("smart") quotes being substituted by an editor. If you have a working version of the query in SQL Assistant history, start with that. Search for help on the editor you are using to figure out how to avoid "smart quotes".

Comment: Sorry for late reply guys. It worked for me after dealing with quotes in my query. Basically I replaced all the quotes to double quotes and then back to single quotes. Wondering how it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some functionalities that are managed (translated) by ODBC itself (as SQL Assistant is using ODBC, it's relevant). I had similar issued when moving dem SQL Assistant to bteq. 
In my case it was LENGTH (which don't exist in Teradata, but is handled by ODBC), after changing to CHAR_LENGTH it worked. Can you post the SQL? Otherwise, go Function by Function through your Query and double-check Teradata documentation (does it exist, has is the parameters I used?).

Answer (score 0):

In the connection string I changed TMODE from ANSI to TERA and it started working.